# Drawing multiple rectangles using a loop in java with collision detection and changing its x and y coordinate (randomly),if collision has occurred.

Tags: java, collision, graphics2d, graphic

Did a lot of googling but was not able to solve this problem.
I want to generate n Number rectangles and draw them on a screen. X,Y are generated randomly and the width and height are based on the font size. My goal is to draw a n number of words on a screen positioned randomly without overlapping existing rectangle. I am using Rectangle for collision detection.

```
private List<Rectangle> rectList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

public boolean checkForCollision(Rectangle r) {
    boolean collision = false;
    if (rectList.size() == 0) {
        rectList.add(r);
        System.out.println("Adding First");
        return collision;
    } else {

        // loop through the list
        Rectangle currRectangle;
        for (int i = 0; i < rectList.size(); i++) {
            currRectangle = rectList.get(i);
            if (r.intersects(currRectangle)) {
                System.out.println(r.toString());
                System.out.println(currRectangle.toString());
                System.out.println("=========================");

                return collision;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("No collision");
        rectList.add(r);
        return !collision;
    }
}
```

This is what I have done to create rectangle and draw a word on it. I am using a loop here.

```
        int width = graphics.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(temp.getWord());
        int height = graphics.getFontMetrics().getHeight();

        Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle(rand.nextInt(1250)+1,     rand.nextInt(650)+1, width, height);
        int xCordinate = (int)newRectangle.getX();
        int yCordinate = (int) newRectangle.getY();

        while(collisonChecker.checkForCollision(newRectangle)){
            //newRectangle = new Rectangle(rand.nextInt(1250)+1, rand.nextInt(650)+1, width, height);
            newRectangle.setLocation(rand.nextInt(1250)+1,rand.nextInt(650)+1);
            collisonChecker.checkForCollision(newRectangle);

        }
        graphics.drawRect((int)newRectangle.getX(), (int)newRectangle.getY(), (int)newRectangle.getWidth(), (int)newRectangle.getHeight());
        newRectangle.setLocation(rand.nextInt(1250)+1,rand.nextInt(650)+1);
        graphics.drawString(temp.getWord().trim(), (int)newRectangle.getX(),(int)newRectangle.getY() );
```

Answer (score 0):

You Never change your return value. No matter, if there's a collision or not , the method returns false. set your return value to true idle there's a collision in the for-loop , that should fix the problem

I hope that helped at least a bit

Comment: Actually, it will return false under two conditions or true (return !collision) if no collision occurs (in theory)

Comment: Have you checked the return values ?

Comment: As I said, in theory, since the op hasn't provided a runnable example which demonstrates the problem, I can only guess at the functionality and from what I've read, the collision method looks okay

Comment: the while loop is going forever and list containing the rectangles is increasing accordingly...

Comment: ps - I'm not the OP (original poster) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this seems "weird" to me...

```
while(collisonChecker.checkForCollision(newRectangle)){
    //newRectangle = new Rectangle(rand.nextInt(1250)+1, rand.nextInt(650)+1, width, height);
    newRectangle.setLocation(rand.nextInt(1250)+1,rand.nextInt(650)+1);
    collisonChecker.checkForCollision(newRectangle);
}
graphics.drawRect((int)newRectangle.getX(), (int)newRectangle.getY(), (int)newRectangle.getWidth(), (int)newRectangle.getHeight());
newRectangle.setLocation(rand.nextInt(1250)+1,rand.nextInt(650)+1);
graphics.drawString(temp.getWord().trim(), (int)newRectangle.getX(),(int)newRectangle.getY() );
```

You create a new `Rectangle`, you check for a collision and start looping while it's `true`, in the loop you change the location of the of the `Rectangle` and check the for a collision but ignore the return result ...? But that's not the worse part...

Once the loop finishes, you randomly generate a new location of `Rectangle`, completely ignoring all the work you did in the loop ...?

Perhaps you should do something more like...

```
while(collisonChecker.checkForCollision(newRectangle)){
    newRectangle.setLocation(rand.nextInt(1250)+1,rand.nextInt(650)+1);
}

graphics.drawRect((int)newRectangle.getX(), (int)newRectangle.getY(), (int)newRectangle.getWidth(), (int)newRectangle.getHeight());
graphics.drawString(temp.getWord().trim(), (int)newRectangle.getX(),(int)newRectangle.getY() );
```

Comment: Thank you very much... I realized where i went wrong :) . Really appreciated.